# the kuberentes did not recognize the local image

Tags: kubernetes

Now I have some trouble to download the kubernetes image from google official repository, then I tried another way to download it:

```
ctr image pull registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/pause:3.6
ctr image tag registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/pause:3.6 registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6
```

I download from the mirror address and tagged it as `registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6`. seems the kubernetes cluster still could not recognize the image. is it possible to make it use the local `registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6` image? what should I do?